# What analyses do I need to run?

Tags: r, distributions, predictive-models

Long post. Question at the bottom.

My data look likes this:

[image]

It consists of the test set accuracies of a series of 50 models formed on training sets.

Using random sampling of the raw observations, I created 100 pairs of test & train sets in a 1:2 ratio. Each test/train pair contained all the raw observations, but each pair was partitioned differently.

Running the 100*50 = 5000 iterations took about 40 hours of wall-time, so in practical terms, I cannot significantly increase the number of randomized test/train sets from 100 to, say, 1000 (an order of magnitude).

I calculated the mean of the 100 accuracies of each model.  They look like this:

[image]

The series of 50 models is parametrized by a single parameter.  By eye, it appears to have three regions: 1:4, 5:10 and 11:50.  Here are the linear models for those three regions, as created by the R function `lm(y~x)`:

[image]

But that is just 'by eye'.  I'd like to know what analyses would allow me to say something more rigorously.

I'm particularly interested in the counter-intuitive region 1:4.  For example, the mean for model #2 is 0.59 greater than model #1. Thus it seems that #2 makes better predictions than #1.

For each of the 100 test/train pairs, I calculated the difference in accuracy between model #2 and model #1.  They look like this:

[image]

With 64 of the values greater than 0, it again seems that #2 makes better predictions than #1.  Their histogram looks like this:

[image]

I've no training in stats. I ran a KS test (appropriately or not) to test if the values #2-#1 follow a Normal distribution with mean 0, `ks.test((M2-M1)/sd(M2-M1),'pnorm')`.  This gave a D value of 0.184 and P value of 0.0023.  I'm guessing the D and P values mean that the #2-#1 does not follow a Normal distribution, maybe because the mean is not zero or the shape is not Normal.

I ran a similar second KS test `ks.test(((M2-M1)-mean(M2-M1))/sd(M2-M1),'pnorm')`, which gave D=0.054, P-value=0.94, which I'm guessing imply that the shape of #2-#1 is close to Normal.

What analyses will allow me to make rigorous statements about 1) several regions of model progression, and 2) model #2 being a better predictor than model #1?

Comment: A Chow test could help you with (1). It tests whether the coefficients are equal in a model estimated on two different sets of data. It requires you to have specific subsets in mind, but it looks like you've identified the most likely break points. You could also compare the AICs of the two models if you know their likelihoods.

Comment: I took a look at Chow on wikipedia.  My concern is that it doesn't take into account the imbalance in the number of observations.  What do you think?  For example the nobs in the 3 regions have the proportions 2:3:20. I also took a first look at AIC and will need to read up on it to understand it, particularly the phrase "the maximized value of the likelihood function for the estimated model"